# undefinend is not a function this.setState react native

Tags: android, react-native, undefined, setstate

I am developing a react native app. When I try to execute the following code I got an error. But setStates on other parts of the same file are working fine.

> undefined is not a
>   function(evaluating'this.setState({firebaseMessages: "Wrong
>   password"})

```
 .catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
      //alert("Wrong password.");
      this.setState({ firebaseMessages: "Wrong password" });
      this.setState({ isModalVisibleFirebase: true });
      this.setState({ loading: false })
      return;
    } else {
      alert(errorMessage);
      return;
    }
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Comment: did you declare the `firebaseMessages` state in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to bind your callback function, try this:

```
catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
        //alert("Wrong password.");
        this.setState({ firebaseMessages: "Wrong password" });
        this.setState({ isModalVisibleFirebase: true });
        this.setState({ loading: false })
        return;
    } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
        return;
    }
    console.log(error);
}.bind(this)) // change this line
```

Alternatively, you can use an ES6 arrow function, like this:

```
catch((error) => {  // change this line
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
        //alert("Wrong password.");
        this.setState({ firebaseMessages: "Wrong password" });
        this.setState({ isModalVisibleFirebase: true });
        this.setState({ loading: false })
        return;
    } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
        return;
    }
    console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use ES5 way of function define your `this` scope will change, use arrow syntax to persist `this` scope.

So now you should do `.catch((error) => {` instead `.catch(function (error){`

```
.catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
      //alert("Wrong password.");
      this.setState({ firebaseMessages: "Wrong password" });
      this.setState({ isModalVisibleFirebase: true });
      this.setState({ loading: false })
      return;
    } else {
      alert(errorMessage);
      return;
    }
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is, assign `this` to some variable and then use that variable to call `setState`.

```
const _this = this; //write this before fetch method
```

and then use like this,

```
_this.setState({ firebaseMessages: "Wrong password" });
```